# Installing packages for Rstudio Docker

Tags: docker, rstudio

I'm trying to use Rstudio on a DigitalOcean server using the [Rstudio docker](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/). Since my experience with linux servers is limited, it's been a bit of a challenge for me.

I'm able to get Rstudio up and running with:

```
docker run -dp 8787:8787 -v /root:/home/rstudio/ -e ROOT=TRUE rocker/hadleyverse
```

However, I'd like to be able to shut down the server and save it to a snapshot when I'm not using it, but not have to re-install packages each time I do so.

Using the the [docker documentation on updating an image](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerimages/#updating-and-committing-an-image), I am able to create a container, install packages on that container, and then commit the changes:

```
docker run -t -i rocker/hadleyverse /bin/bash
install.r randomForest
exit
docker commit \<CONTAINER_ID> michael91/ms:v1
```

However, once I make the commit, I am unable to run the updated image properly. I try and run it as follows:

```
docker run -dp 8787:8787 -v /root:/home/rstudio/ -e ROOT=TRUE michael91/ms:v1
```

When I do so, Rstudio server is not activated, as it is when I run the original rocker/hadleyverse version. I've tried making commits with and without installing packages; either way it doesn't seem to work. Obviously I'm doing something incorrectly, but I'm not sure what. If anyone could offer me some guidance, I'd really appreciate it.

Edit: Thanks a lot VonC; that did the trick.

Comment: Great! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to take the tour (http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Note that it's sufficient to just append the default command to the end of your container; e.g.  `docker run -dp 8787:8787 -v /root:/home/rstudio/ -e ROOT=TRUE michael91/ms:v1 supervisord`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be because the new committed image has lost its `CMD` directive that was present in [`rocker-org/rocker/rstudio/Dockerfile#L58`](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/blob/13414ee0be5656ef4a451cb1aab51ec5c614cdea/rstudio/Dockerfile#L58).

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d /supervisord.conf"]
```

Try and create a new Dockerfile:

```
FROM michael91/ms:v1
## Add RStudio binaries to PATH
ENV PATH /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/:$PATH 
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
EXPOSE 8787

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]
```

And build it as `michael91/ms:v2`.

Then see v2 works better than v1 when it comes to activating RStudio:

```
docker run -dp 8787:8787 -v /root:/home/rstudio/ -e ROOT=TRUE michael91/ms:v2
```